# From Frege to Gödel - German equivalent?

Tags: reference-request, lo.logic, ho.history-overview

I know this question does not quite fit here, but I felt it could best be answered here. I recently stumbled upon the book *From Frege to Gödel*, which is a sourcebook containing some of the most important papers in the development of logic, translated into English. However, I realize that most of these papers have actually been written in German and the book thus contains mostly translations. Since my mother tongue is German, I wondered whether there was a German (or native language) equivalent to the book; that is, one containing the same or similar articles but in their original form (i.e. language)?

Thank you in advance for any hints or even definite answers!

Max.

Comment: You might want to check [Berker, Kreiser'86 -  kommentierte Auswahl zur Geschichte der modernen Logik](http://www.worldcat.org/title/logik-texte-kommentierte-auswahl-zur-geschichte-der-modernen-logik/oclc/36450770?referer=di&ht=edition)

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will try it out. Do you have any idea if it contains (roughly) the same papers? I'm unable to find a content summary anywhere.

Comment: Why don't you just read the original papers? I think the purpose of this book was only to translate them into English.

Comment: I was looking for a collection simply because it's cheaper than buying the original papers at Springer & co. For convenience too.